# How can i show that$(F_{n-1}F_{n+2})^2+(2F_nF_{n+1})^2=(F_{2n+2})^2$ by combinatorial proof?

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

How can i show that 
$$(F_{n-1}F_{n+2})^2+(2F_nF_{n+1})^2=(F_{2n+2})^2$$ by combinatorial proof?
Here $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.
I got stuck on this problem.
I want to solve it by combinatorial proof.
plz help ㅜㅜ

Comment: Can you format this with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ? Right now the equality in the title is a bit hard to parse.

Comment: @AirConditioner sorry I don't know how to use it. I will try to use it later.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I tried to make 1-1 correspondense to (A,B,C,D)&(E,F,G,H) and (X,Y), where A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H is length n, n, 
 n+1, n+1, n-1, n-1, n+2, n+2 tiling and X,Y is both length 2n+2 tiling. but it is too hard for me ㅠㅠ

Comment: let's define F0=1

Comment: OK, $F_0=1$ makes sense.

Comment: Note that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ and $F_{n-1}=F_{n+1}-F_n$. This can be used to simplify the left-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

Using Axel Kemper's hint we get that 
$$
(F_{n-1}F_{n+2})^2 + (2F_nF_{n+1})^2 = ((F_{n+1}-F_n)(F_{n+1}+F_n))^2 + 4F_n^2F_{n+1}^2
$$
$$
= (F_{n+1}^2 - F_n^2)^2 + 4F_n^2F_{n+1}^2 = (F_{n+1}^2 + F_n^2)^2.
$$
Thus it suffices to show that
$$
F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2 = F_{2n+2}.
$$
Now take a tiling of a $1 \times (2n+2)$ board with $1 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ tiles. The number of such tilings is $F_{2n+2}$. Distinguish two cases, the first case is if there is a $2 \times 1$ tile in the middle and the second case is if there is no such tile.

I think you will be able to finish the proof yourself.